# GWTP Bootstraper doesn't work

Tags: gwt, bootstrapping, gwtp, gwt-platform

I've followed instruction from [here](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/get-started/Bootstrap-Code.html#bootstrapper). But unfortunately it doesn't work at all.

According to documentation I should:

1. Implement `Bootstrapper` interface.
2. Write implementation of method `void onBootstrap()`.
3. Register this implementation in **.gwt.xml file.

Which I've done.

Here are my classes:

```
package pl.daniel.cms.client.gin;

import com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT;
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Bootstrapper;

public class MyBootstrapper implements Bootstrapper {

    @Override
    public void onBootstrap() {
        GWT.log("Bootstraper Test");
    }
}
```

---

```
<set-configuration-property name="gwtp.bootstrapper" value="pl.daniel.cms.client.gin.MyBootstrapper"/>
```

But it doesn't work.

I use `<gwtp.version>1.5.2</gwtp.version>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it works. The bootstrapper will be, well, **bootstrapped** (if you put a breakpoint on your GWT.log statement you'll see it executed + some additional magic there)

Also, you're not revealing the place after custom bootstrapping. Please change it to

```
@Inject
PlaceManager placeManager;
@Override
public void onBootstrap() {
    logger.fine("Hi there");
    placeManager.revealPlace(new PlaceRequest.Builder().nameToken(NameTokens.HOME).build());
}
```

To see at least something on the screen

Comment: I see normally app. It just Dosent work. I will try clean and restart everything.